# Проверить покупателей за каждый месяц

Tags: sql

Есть задание, вывести покупателей, стоимость покупки и кол-во покупок за каждый месяц.

```
SELECT C.CONTACT_LAST, S.TOTAL_VALUE, S.QTY_ORDERED 
FROM CUSTOMER C
JOIN SALES S ON S.CUST_NO = C.CUST_NO 
WHERE (S.TOTAL_VALUE = (SELECT MIN(S.TOTAL_VALUE) FROM SALES S) 
AND S.PAID = 'y' 
AND EXTRACT(YEAR From S.ORDER_DATE) = '1993') 
OR (S.TOTAL_VALUE = (SELECT MAX(S.TOTAL_VALUE) FROM SALES S) 
AND S.PAID = 'y' AND EXTRACT(YEAR From S.ORDER_DATE) = '1993')  
ORDER BY S.TOTAL_VALUE ASC;
```

Подскажите, как проверить каждый месяц?

Comment: @Akina, просто я не понимаю, как правильно реализовать. И как понять, по фотографиям не лечим?

Comment: *как понять, по фотографиям не лечим?* Удаляете картинку, выкладываете - скрипт CREATE TABLE, скрипт с тестовыми данными INSERT INTO (всё - форматированным текстовым кодом), показываете требуемый результат для именно таких данных, подробно объясняете логику получения результата из показанных исходных данных.

Comment: @Akina поймите, если я бы знал логику, получения свой задачи, я бы не спросил.

Comment: *если я бы знал логику, получения свой задачи, я бы не спросил.* Это Вы сейчас сказали, что понятия не имеете, что именно надо сделать?

Comment: @Akina есть задача. Найти покупателей за каждый  месяц. Все остальное я реализовал. Может быть есть пример поиска за каждый месяц?

Comment: Ну так и выложите пример данных и требуемый ответ для именно таких данных. Какие сложности-то? Но пример такой, чтобы его можно было скопировать и применить для воссоздания таблиц - т.е. в виде готовых SQL-скриптов.

Comment: @Akina, я не могу выложить вам данные в виде файла.